# How can i refactor this function in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, observer-pattern

i have 3 observables, the first one emits an object that contains an neccesary id in the second observable and this one, emits an value required in the last observable. I do not even know if there's a rxjs operator to solve this easier. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: The operator you want is `switchMap`. There are plenty of examples on StackOverflow on how to use that :)

Comment: SwitchMap should do? Nesting subscribes is not really a good idea..

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

I changed all your names because you posted a picture, not your code. I'm not going to copy it all out :P

```ts
getRad(): void {

  this.getCurDep().pipe(
    switchMap(dep => this.getCurSer(dep.id).pipe(
      map(serie => ({dep, serie}))
    )),
    switchMap(({dep, serie}) => this.getCurrSubser(dep.id, serie.id).pipe(
      map(subserie => ({dep, serie, subserie}))
    ))
  ).subscribe(console.log);

}
```